# How to apply an XSLT transformation over flowVar variable on DataWeave Mule?

Tags: xslt, mule, dataweave

I would like to apply an XSLT transformation over a flowVar variable which contains an XML, and I don't know how to specify that on DataWeave Mule.

Thanks in advance,
Juan Andres

Answer (score 0):

In the dataweave, you don't need to specify XSLT. Some operations which you would like to do in XSLT are also available in Dataweave.

Let us know what exact is your source/target format.

Answer (score 0):

MuleSoft recommends using DataWeave as it's a universal transformation engine, which replaces a multiple of separate transformers that could used. If you have an XLST, you don't supply this to dataweave as it won't be understood. You will have to recreate the transformation that you want to use within dataweave from the XLST - there is no option to convert or access an XLST from a dataweave transformation.

There is an XLST transformer that is shipped in Mule; it's outside of dataweave and was available as the default in earlier versions. You will not find it within the Mule Palette, but there is an example given here - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xslt-transformer - but this might not be available in later versions of Mule.